# addFooterView for a ListView that is defined in the xml

Tags: android, xml, android-listview

I've got a ListView, which is fully defined in the xml file. Now I want to add a footer to thi s list so that the last element of the list became a button.

So firstly I do this: `View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.add_new, null);`, where add_new is the layout for my footer

Now I know that I need to do smth like this:
 `listViewInstance.addFooterView(v);`

But i dont really have that instance as my ListView is defined in an xml file. So what do I write instead of listViewInstance? Is there a way to get its instance somehow from an xml?

Thanks in advance xxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ListActivity.getListView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#getListView%28%29) if you are using a ListActivity or [Activity.findViewById()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29) to get the reference to the list view otherwise.

Comment: Thanks a lot that is very helpful I will accept an answer in 10 min xx